# Magento 2 unable to send mail

Tags: email, smtp, magento2, ssmtp

Magento 2 - I'm migrating a Magento 1.9.3 site to a new instance of Magento 2.1.3.
Its actually a complete new install.

I just cannot work out how to get Magento 2 to send email via a smtp.
I have tried to setup ssmtp but i have failed

I'm using ipage for email, we could use gmail if its easier

I need to send user name and password when sending emails

```
mailhub=smtp.ipage.com:587
AuthUser=sales@deckside.com.au
AuthPass=********
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have try with cron.